# Rails 4 - How to get specific records based on where conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Sale` model with an `:offer_end` column with a `date` data type. I would like to display specific records of `Sale` where `:offer_end >= Date.today`. I tried to get this to work in the controller but im not sure what is the correct syntax to achieve this. This is what im currently doing which isnt working:

```
  def index
    @shops = Shop.all
    @sales = Sale.where("offer_end >= Date.today", {offer_end: params[:offer_end]})
  end
```

Comment: You can do this using scope, just create a parameter scope in your Sale model and pass your params value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can't pass the `Date.today` as a string to the query, it will be passed to the database and it won't understand it.

The query should be something like this

```
@sale = Sale.where('offer_end > ?', Date.today)
```

The `Date.today` will be evaluated then passed as a value to the query.

You could replace the `Date.today` with any date object or date string, which in your case seems to be in the`params[:offer_end]`

```
@sale = Sale.where('offer_end > ?', params[:offer_end])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use scope for these type of operations:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :get_products, ->(date){where(" sales.offer_end >= ? ", date)}
end
```

In controller you can use this scope as below:

```
@sales = Sale.get_products(params[:offer_end])
```

or you can use it directly in controller:

```
@sales = Sale.where("offer_end >= ?", Date.today)
```

and you can use `params[:offer_end]` instead of `Date.today`

Comment: `" Date.today <= ?", date` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Corrected the mistake.

Comment: I couldnt get the scope part to work, but the second option worked. Thanks!